# Finding exact amount of each character in a string

Tags: javascript, function, object

So I ran into a interview question that was quite complex (at least for me), I have not been able to find an answer as yet. It is as follows:

Write a function that takes a string and returns an object with the key being the specific letter and the value being how many times the specific letter is found in the string.
EX:

```
myfn('My name is Taylor');

newObj{
a: 2,
e: 1,
i: 1,
l: 1,
m: 2,
n: 1,
o: 1,
r: 1,
s: 1,
t: 1,
y: 2
}
```

the `newObj` is what it is returning.

Comment: And what was your approach?

Comment: I got the basics, 
    var myfn = function(str){
      var newObj{};
      for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
      }
    }
But am completely stuck on what else to put into it.

Comment: You should refer to the `newObj[str[i]]` and set it to `1` if it was not set before, otherwise increment it by 1.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, right on the money

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function takes the string as its argument.

```
function getObj(str) {

    //define a new object
    var obj = {};

    // loop over the string
    for (var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i++) {

      // set the letter variable to the element the loop is on
      // drop the letter to lowercase (if you want to
      // record capitalised letters too drop the
      // `.toLowerCase()` part)
      var letter = str[i].toLowerCase();

      // if the key doesn't exist on the object create a new one,
      // set to the letter and set it to zero
      if (!obj[letter]) { obj[letter] = 0; }

      // increment the number for that key (letter)
      obj[letter]++;
    }

    // finally return the object
    return obj;
}

var obj = getObject(str);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xgd50z19/)

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer andy, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.

```
var myFn = function(str){
  var newObj = {};
  for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
    if(newObj[str[i]]){
      newObj[str[i]]++;
    } else{
      newObj[str[i]] =1;
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

edited for spelling errors and syntax

Comment: `newObj[str[i]] =1` should be `newObj[str[i]] =0` i think. But good work.

Comment: To avoid repeating `newObj[str[i]]` three times, you could use `if(!++newObj[str[i]]){ newObj[str[i]]=1; }` or `newObj[str[i]] = ++newObj[str[i]] || 1` or something like that.

Comment: You might have to explain incremental prefixes if the OP is new to JS, @Oriol.

Comment: I am fairly new yes, I just finished up a bootcamp called DevMountain.  Now I'm trolling around looking for interview questions so I can get a job in app development.

Comment: Good luck. Hope it goes well.